# If $T$ is a normal linear map on an inner product space $V$, show $T-\lambda I$ is normal

Tags: linear-transformations

This is my attempt.
Let $T$ be a normal linear map on an inner product space $V$ and $\lambda$ is any scalar. 
Then by definition $T \circ T^\star = T^\star \circ T$. 
Now consider $(T-\lambda I)^\star = T^\star - \bar{\lambda}I$.
Then
$(T-\lambda I)^\star \circ (T-\lambda I) = (T^\star - \bar{\lambda}I)\circ(T - \lambda I)$.
Can I simply distribute these brackets? Technically, theyre compositions of linear maps, so I don't think we can (because they aren't products).
It looks like I want to show
$(T^\star - \bar{\lambda}I)\circ(T - \lambda I) =(T-\lambda I)\circ (T^\star - \bar{\lambda}I) $

Comment: They are (non-commutative) products in the ring of endomrphisms fo $V$

Comment: I might not understand the terminilogy. Are you saying that that composition won't commutate (so it won't show my result)?

Comment: Yes, you can distribute, precisely because you are dealing with linear maps. In fact, $f\circ(g+h)=f\circ g+f\circ h$, because $\bigl(f\circ(g+h)\bigr)(v)=f\bigl(g(v)+h(v)\bigr)=f\bigl(g(v)\bigr)+f\bigl(h(v)\bigr)=\bigl(f\circ g+f\circ h\bigr)(v)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Cheers! How do we ensur that $(T-\lambda I)$ is linear, given that $T$ is linear?

Comment: @PaulWoch: It is guaranteed by the definition of addition of linear maps, and of multiplication of linear maps by a scalar.

Comment: @PaulWoch Sums of linear maps are linear.